# Comparing two byte arrays in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, compare

I have `byte[]` stored in a SQL Server database as `varbinary(64)` and I need to find a specific row with input `byte[]`. I'm using Entity Framework to access the database, thus I can run a linq query like this:

```cs
private MyTable GetMyTable(byte[] inputArray) 
{
   return _context.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Hash.SequenceEqual(inputArray));
}
```

The issue is that `SequenceEqual` can't be translated into SQL query and the query will be evaluated locally (which is is undesirable behavior). Is it possible to replace `SequenceEqual` for simple compare operator `==`?  Or is this approach error-prone? Is there any better alternatives than this?

```cs
private MyTable GetMyTable(byte[] inputArray) 
{
   return _context.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Hash == inputArray);
}
```

Note that my byte arrays will range from 32 to 64 bytes so it's not going to be huge array comparisons.

Comment: You can use Array.Equals(object, object)

Comment: Actually, using Array.Equals seem much more "right" in this case than ==. Thank you so much @jdweng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to replace SequenceEqual for simple compare operator ==?

Probably yes, that will be tranlated to SQL as

```
  SELECT ...
  FROM [MyTable] AS [c]
  WHERE [c].[Hash] = @__inputArray_0
```

And `=` in SQL Server for binary/varbinary performs a byte-wise binary comparison on the values, ignoring trailing 0's.  So if that's the comparison you want, then your're good to go.

Comment: I tested both methods, == and Array.Equals as @jdweng suggested and they seems that both transforms to this. I just wanted to be sure. Thanks for your help!